# How do you deep link to an answer?

Tags: support, answers, hyperlinks

I've seen it done, but can't seem to figure out how to link someone to an answer on a question.

I might be trying to help someone I work with and I find the right question and I want to send them to that page without having to say "check the second answer from the top".  Is there some simple way to get the deep link to the question?

I've seen it used, just can't figure out how to get that deep link myself.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/45598

Comment: But hey we aren't supposed to go there anymore, just sposed to duplicate everything in every little meta! </sarcasm>

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There's a "share" link at the bottom of every answer.

[image: Share]

If you click on that, it pops open a dialog that gives you a shortened URL directly to the answer instead of to the question.

If you want to give your friend a long URL to the answer (with the question title slug, so they know where they're going), you can just put the shortened URL in your browser and get the long URL from your address bar after the redirect.

Comment: Beware that the short URL includes your user id; see [Privacy leak in permalink?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74274/privacy-leak-in-permalink) Also note that Ctrl/Cmd-clicking "share" will work in most browsers, to open the long URL in a new tab. Somehow Shift-clicking it to open in a new window does not work though.

Comment: Wow, I just considered that to be for Social stuff.  Thanks.