# My answer was cloned and improved what should I do?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, ethics

My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24660825/1129332) was [cloned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29792507/1129332) and improved what should I do?

- Should I delete my answer in favor of the better one?
- Should I apply the improvement of the cloned answer on my own?
- Should I add a reference to the better answer?

Or is it some thing else?

Comment: Is it *better* or is it just another way to do it? I, personally, wouldn't delete it. I might consider editing my answer and saying "Here's another take on my answer" and link to it just to show good sportsmanship.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen No, it's actually an upgrade to my idea. I can's say another way, it's the same way only better.

Comment: That person probably should have just edited your answer then. I don't think you should delete your answer if it isn't wrong. I don't think making your answer look like theirs is a good idea either. 1) Plagarism and 2) that's likely to come across as a malicious tit for tat move. You could add a reference to the other answer but I don't think you're obligated to. Personally, I'd just leave it alone.

Comment: Your answer is the most upvoted one there. Why would you want to delete it? You can try to add more details, to improve formatting, etc.

Comment: ForceBru: Ilya's answer is far from being the most up-voted one on that question. BSMP: It's considered "bad form" to "improve" another user's post when that is changing the content / effect.

Comment: Is it just me, or is that a shockingly bad question, to end up with 84 upvotes?

Answer (score 11):

I would upvote the other answer, and if needed, leave a comment suggesting further improvement.

It looks like the other answer gave credit where credit was due, which is something we want to encourage here.

- There's no reason to delete your answer, it isn't a bad answer and it looks like it may have already helped a few people.
- Unless you intend to take the information from the new answer and
  **expand on it**, there's really no reason to copy the new info to your own answer.
- I'm not sure what reference you're wanting to add to the other answer, but you may be better off adding a comment; let the other author make the decision to edit.

Comment: If the OP means providing a link to the other "better" answer, there's always [sharing the answer's link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251505/how-do-you-deep-link-to-an-answer).