# Etiquette for adding to an accepted answer

Tags: discussion, comments, accepted-answer, etiquette, quality-improvement

I want to know how to contribute to an answer I'm going to accept.

I did my own research, and using the answers (they're guidelines), I was able to solve my problem. My dilemma is this:

1. I want to **add** to the answer I intend to accept (ie, I can improve it), but **I do not wish to answer my question**, as I feel that the answer should get credit.
2. The content I wish to add is **not small enough for comments**.
3. I can **edit** into **the question**, but I don't want to do that. Question should **not** contain the answer.

I want to know what is the best etiquette for this situation, giving credit to the persons whose answers I find good (but not enough) while adding my own.

Of course, if it's bad practice to do so, please let me know.

Comment: If the answer was really helpful, you can give it a bounty.

Comment: Opinions are almost never answers.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Poor choice of words. I clarify [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296891/3887393).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Add an additional answer if you would like to contribute your own answer to your question.

Be sure to cite other answers as appropriate for any of their work that you use in your answer.

If you want to accept another user's answer, instead of your own, you're more than welcome to do so.

Answer (score 17):

In addition to what [Servy mentions in his answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296809/etiquette-for-adding-to-an-accepted-answer/296810#296810), it often helps to provide links to the other reference answer.  You can do this by collecting the link from the "share" option at the bottom of the post (for more information on sharing answers see [Bill's answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251505/how-do-you-deep-link-to-an-answer/251506#251506)).

Adding an extension to another user's answer is a good way of adding addenda or fixing potential hangups in the primary solution.

As always, consider upvoting the other helpful answer (I have likewise upvoted [Servy's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296809/etiquette-for-adding-to-an-accepted-answer/296810#296810)).  I don't see any problem with accepting your own answer since it's the actual solution to the problem, but you can accept the other answer that was the most helpful in finding your solution.  Either way is fine.

Answer (score 15):

If your extra details are a natural extension of something already provided in one of the answers, if your extra information isn't really any different but merely makes it easier to understand one of the existing answers, then one thing you can do is ***edit the answer***. Don't do this on your own, as many will consider that rude. Comments like "I went with this approach, but I would like to add some non-obvious information needed to make this work. Would you mind if I edit it into your answer?" are not common, but when they do appear, they are typically well-received from what I've seen.

If your extra details are not a natural extension of something already provided, or if the answer is no, then you can still post an answer of your own, as suggested by Servy.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with the general sentiments provided in both answers offered so far, particularly the guidance that posting a new answer that actually addresses the question squarely is better than editing an existing answer from someone else.

However, to all that I would add a strong caution against accepting someone else's answer just because you'd rather they get some extra reputation or otherwise are granted some degree of credit. I.e. I agree with the statement ["either way is fine"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296811/) only insofar as that's true if all else is in fact equal. But rarely is that actually the case.

If another answer to your question besides the one you post yourself is in fact the *best* answer to your question, then by all means accept it. But if none of the answers really *answer* the question, or even if they do but not as well as your own, then please *accept your own*.

Others seeking an answer to the same question later will appreciate it. The primary purpose of an accepted answer is to draw attention to the answer that best addresses the question that was asked. This allows others who later come across the Q&A to quickly find the information they need.

The reputation bonus to the person whose answer is accepted is nice of course, but all of us should be mature and professional enough to understand that we all share the common goal of making the Stack Overflow content as high-quality as possible, including optimizing the retrieval of information as much as we can. If that means one's answer winds up not accepted because the questioner posted and self-accepted an answer that really did a better job answering the original question, so be it. No one should ever be upset about that.

As the questioner, please do not accept an answer inferior to your own out of some sense of justice or obligation. That might be the "feel good" solution, but it fails to make the quality of the information on the site as good as it could be otherwise.

Comment: Exactly - accepting is not a charity action. It has real effects for other readers.

Answer (score 2):

#### Is *opinion* the correct term for what you want to add?

**opinion** : *a view or judgment formed about something, not necessarily based on fact or knowledge.*

You use this word pretty specifically in your question multiple times.

If it really is **opinion** then do not add it to someone else's answer, write your own answer with your own **opinion** or commentary.

Comment: OK. **opinion** was probably not the best choice of a word. I meant that I wanted the answer to be specific and to-the-point, and while the **best** answer was helpful, I could improve significantly on it..

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across a similar situation as yours in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30721567/limit-tweepy-stream-to-a-specific-number/30721672#30721672)

The person that answered my question did give me an advice of where I was going wrong with my approach, and also provided an alternative for it.

His solution didn't work as you can read in the comments. Few days past by and I was still doing research to find a solution to my problem and came across one.

I did feel it necessary to edit his post for the following reasons:

1. His contribution to the code is greater than mine (to make it work)
2. If it wasn't for his original answer, I wouldn't be able to do more research towards the correct one.
3. I felt that he deserves the credit because of the previous reasons, and that an edit is more appropriate so future users are able to obtain the code from one spot instead of having to scroll up and down and see what's better and why.