# Add Peer-Reviewed Answer

Tags: feature-request

## The Problem

Often I've found that the best answer to a question is not the accepted answer. While Community Wiki offers a way to let the crowd decide, I think SO would benefit from the feature I've described below.

## Assumptions

1. It is well-accepted that people are bad at gauging their own level of expertise.
2. The crowd can often find the most-appropriate answer.
3. The crowd is always responsive - users become inactive.
4. The answer to a question can change over time.

## Related Questions

- [Deleting an accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258602/deleting-an-accepted-answer)
- [Etiquette for adding to an accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296809/etiquette-for-adding-to-an-accepted-answer)
- [Add Feature to Report an Answer as "Provably Incorrect"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288148/add-feature-to-report-an-answer-as-provably-incorrect)

## Proposed Solution

I propose that we add a peer-level answer to the right of the requester's approved answer. See the screenshot below.

[image: Peer-Reviewed / Community Answer]

This would allow us to know if a significant fraction of SO users found a community answer better in some way than the "official" answer.

Comment: Sounds good,  but what about the most important part - how would the community arrive at an "accepted" answer? Through votes?

Comment: Through a consensus algorithm (minimum quality votes perhaps). It could be updated automatically to reflect the current "best" available community answer.

Comment: @Pekka웃 the most upvoted answer probably , maybe with a floor of 1.. would an accepted answer that is the highest scoring answer have two checks, or a third new check that is for useraccepted+communityaccepted? I guess probably only add the community accepted check on posts that need it , leave other questions alone. I like your idea a lot. much better than many other proposed ideas in [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264045/lets-move-some-negatively-scored-answers-from-the-top-spot). Most ideas seem too complicated, this would be pretty easy and straight forward.

Comment: If another answer has more votes than the accepted answer we already know the community rates it more highly. Why do we need a special mark to tell us which number is bigger?

Comment: I somewhat doubt SE's layout will grow much in breadth. Also, my own contribution to that topic: [Deemphasise the accept mark if there's an answer the community strongly prefers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253752)

Comment: @RobertLongson Because of the giant green check mark and the prominence given to the submitter's choice right now. Most often a question will be asked by a novice - who may rate answers less effectively than the community.

Comment: @RobertLongson I agree with you, but seems a lot of people want it changed (see the link I posted in comment above).. so if it's going to be changed I think this is the best solution.

Comment: @WillBickford, Its a nice idea, but in my experience voting here is very very fickle.  It seems to me that a significant number just vote for the sake of voting to get their badges.

Comment: Isn't the whole concept of an "accepted answer" a little dated?  Whether the OP found an answer acceptable or not is of really no importance to the community, beyond a notification that their particular issue has been solved.  People that come across the question in the future could care less whether the OP accepted an answer or not.

Comment: @RobertLongson Sometimes when an answer has more upvotes than the chosen one, it is not immediately after the chosen answer. This situation should be improved.

Comment: @DanielCheung Use the votes tab to sort answers by votes.

Comment: @RobertLongson yes, but i think the site should change the default behavior.

Comment: @DanielCheung that **is** the default behaviour

Comment: @RobertLongson Oops, I seems I'm haven't stayed long enough on StackOverflow :D. Thanks you for clarifying.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The Problem
>
> Often I've found that the best answer to a question is not the
>   accepted answer.

Why is this a problem?

Marking an answer as accepted does not make it any more correct or valued by the community. It simply means that the OP selected the answer as the one they personally found the most helpful.

I think *most* SO users are savvy enough to recognize the difference between the answer with the most votes and the answer with the green check mark, and *some* of them probably read more than one answer when researching a problem.

Suggesting a rather major site redesign to solve a problem most users don't have, seems like making mountains out of molehills...

Comment: It's a problem because lower quality content is promoted above the higher quality content. Sure, most veterans know that. Not all readers who have barely ever used the site before do. I've seen quite a few questions where very poor answers that promote bad practices but look "easy" or "answer the question" but ultimately will cause problems are accepted and accumulate a ton of upvotes because of it. A "community" accept may not be the answer, but there *is* a problem of promoting bad practice.

Comment: @jpmc26 If you ever see me trying to debate an issue that's not programming related, please kindly remind me that it won't end well and that it's better for me to not engage. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This is a good idea, it has a real problem but I'm unconvinced by the solution

> Often I've found that the best answer to a question is not the accepted answer.

First, best is pretty subjective. Do you mean best in your opinion, or best in the communities opinion? The first is dictated by whether you have up voted or not, and the second by the score.

> It is well-accepted that people are bad at gauging their own level of expertise.

Yes.

> The crowd can often find the most-appropriate answer.

Yes - currently through voting.

> The crowd is always responsive - users become inactive.

Perhaps, and yes they do.

> The answer to a question can change over time.

Yes, it can.

> I propose that we add a peer-level answer to the right of the accepted answer.

First things first, why does it need a new mark - don't the votes already cover this? If it is more up voted than the accepted answer then it's better?

And next to - maybe not. The main thread pane is 600px wide, plus some white space and a 220 sidebar. This makes it close to 1050px wide in total. Adding another answer to the side (without the sidebar) makes it 1460px wide. Bear in mind that 1280 x 800 is still a commonish screen size, making it that much wider does affect the content a lot:

[image]

While it could be worse, this is on a 1920x1080 monitor, so there is plenty of space. It really doesn't fit on a 1280 monitor.

---

#### An alternative?

Instead, I have a different solution. It doesn't have a new "checkmark" or similar, it just changes the exiting behaviour.

Rather than forcing answers to the top, an accept has the same effect as +3 and then +10% of the absolute value. This adapted score isn't shown, but it is used in sorting.

The +3 means that any post with an accepted answer at 0 and another at 1 still keeps the accepted one on top. Instead of the 0 score, it would be sorted as if it had 3.3 - i.e. above the answer with 1.

However, an accepted, up voted but wrong answer at 20 would be taken over by a post at 30 - 20 + 3 + 10% = 25.3, which is less than 30.

The 10% is of the absolute value because otherwise a post at -4 would become -7.7, or -8 when sorted. The accept always boosts the score - in this case to -0.9 or -1 . Workings: -4 + 3 = -1 + (0.1 * abs(-1)) = -0.9, which rounds to -1.

[Also posted here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264452/252153).

Answer (score -3):

The question is good, so I gave an upvote. But I don't agree adding a "community accepted answer". Rather, the site **should move more upvoted non-accepted answers right after the accepted answer but it can do some visual effects like tinting the background color**.

E.g. Look at this: [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)

Sometimes, you might not even notice the 500 upvoted answer if you don't scroll down.

The site seems to order answers according to the change of date. I suggest **creating a *new* default formula to take account of the change of date & the number of upvotes**, like so:

```
orderFromTop(votes, changeOfDate) = k(votes) + l(changeOfDate), where k,l are constants
```