# How do I deep link to a comment?

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

Related but for answers only: [How do you deep link to an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251505/how-do-you-deep-link-to-an-answer)

How do I do the same for a comment? The only way I found is inspecting the pages source code and find the comment's `id` in the HTML, but is there a more direct way?

Comment: This is a test comment for linking purposes.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/direct-link-to-a-comment

Comment: There are [multiple duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/5436) for that one. You can consider [this Q/A about improving the usability/intuitiveness of direct comment links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193594/390859).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just take the link off the timestamp (right click, "Copy Link Address" in Chrome).

For example, the comment I left on your question is:

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303729/how-to-deep-link-to-comment#comment239572_303729
```

Or, so you can follow it:
[How to deep link to comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303729/how-to-deep-link-to-comment#comment239572_303729)

Comment: More reading on the [MSE feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/direct-link-to-a-comment)