# Is there a way to link to an answer without my user id?

Tags: support, answers, hyperlinks

This question and it's answers show how to get a link to a specific answer (as opposed to the question which it answers). 
[How do you deep link to an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251505/how-do-you-deep-link-to-an-answer)
But the link contains the user id. Is there a way to get the link without the user id?
If I am not mistaken, such link should exist because when I look at my own profile, I am given links to my own answers which don't include my user id. For example: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064524/plotting-shaded-uncertainty-region-in-line-plot-in-matplotlib-when-data-has-nans/43069856#43069856`.

Comment: Just remove the user ID from the URL.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The only part that is required is answer ID: "https://stackoverflow.com/a/43079654", user ID is used to count how many times particular link was shared (so you can get "[announcer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer)" badge for example). So click "share" button, copy url and remove the last part.

Comment: being able to make this a default would be far better in my opinion