# Allow share link to not include my user ID

Tags: feature-request

I often find myself sharing links to answers where I don't want others to be able to tell who I am on Stack Overflow.

It's really annoying to have to [copy/paste the link and then delete the last portion of it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346107/is-there-a-way-to-link-to-an-answer-without-my-user-id) every single time I want to share it.

It would be nice if there was a boolean setting for me in my profile that would take my user ID off of the sharing links.

Comment: Could be done with a userscript. I've one that drops the user ID and then formats the link into markdown syntax as `[<question title>](<url without user id>)` - makes linking to stuff in comments easier.

Comment: [These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258989/manually-adding-a-userscript-to-google-chrome/5259212) sorts of things? (I've never used userscripts before.)

Comment: Yes - it's like a mini addon for the browser. You need another addon like Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey to manage them but after that it's just a matter of making a JavaScript file. [This site has more info](https://greasyfork.org/en)

Comment: I'm obviously missing something - why not just copy the URL from the browser?

Comment: @Mureinik it's too long in some cases, I guess.

Comment: Here's my userscript you can use [NoUserIdShareLinks](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/NoUserIdShareLinks.user.js)

Comment: @Vlaz, a link to your UserScript?

Comment: @DragandDrop [here](https://pastebin.com/qW7imY90) I've not published it since I'm too lazy to make it better - currently it just dumps the link in the console. Feel free to make any adjustments you see fit and publish, if you wish. I grant thee the MIT license blessing.

Comment: @DragandDrop oh, right instructions to use - add the userscript and then questions will have a new button on the bottom called "share markdown" - it's alongside the other ones where "share" and "flag" are. Clicking it prints the markdown in the console, so press F12 and copy it.

Comment: You mean "sharing *outside* of Stack Overflow", right? If you post an answer or a comment in here, it's pretty clear from who it came.

Comment: @Mureinik because answers don't have a URL I can link to. For questions, that is what I do, but I don't know of any way to share answers with a URL.

Comment: @Mureinik just discovered that [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271480/5049813) solves that problem